# What's a convenient way to delete all aliases?

Tags: bash, alias

With `zsh` I can do this to delete all aliases:

```
% unalias $( alias + )
```

I am looking for the equivalent in `bash`.

Comment: Just like zsh: `unalias -a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unalias -a
```

according to the man page.

Comment: or `help unalias`

Comment: Which is POSIX and works in bash, zsh and any POSIX shell.

Comment: better do `\unalias -a` for a case where `unalias` also alias-ed for something else :D